Tkinter toolbar space allocation increases with each new figure in a loop
I have a GUI that plots an image figure in a loop based on a button click. I'm adding a toolbar to this figure so you can zoom in and out, but despite destroying all the children in the assigned frame at every loop, the toolbar appears to get assigned more and more space with each loop (i.e., the figure frame gets wider and wider). Here are the relevant functions. I've tried everything and it just refuses to cooperate. Any help would be much appreciated. The problem is likely in the "pick_single" function below. In it, I have a block to destroy all children, but apparently some remnant of the toolbar is being kept somewhere.
#function to remove several of the toolbar buttons and only keep zoom and home
class Toolbar(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    NavigationToolbar2Tk.toolitems = [t for t in NavigationToolbar2Tk.toolitems if
                                  t[0] not in ('Back','Forward','Pan','Subplots','Save',None)]
    
    def set_message(self, s):
        pass

def create_plot(image_cur):
    global counter, txt_files
    # f = Figure(figsize=(2,1.5),dpi=250,frameon=False)
    f = Figure(figsize=(plotwidth, plotheight),dpi=dpi,frameon=False,tight_layout = True)
    f.clear()
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    p1=ax.imshow(image_cur)
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.set_title(str(counter+1)+' of '+str(len(txt_files)),fontsize=5)
    return f  

# function that picks the center of a scale through a mouse click
def pickc(event):
    global st_cent, counter, store_centers,pxmm,trigg,cnt_r
    x=event.xdata
    y=event.ydata
    store_centers[counter,:] = [x,y]
    
    if trigg == -1:
        cnt_r += 1
        ratio_coords[cnt_r,:] = [x,y]
        if cnt_r == 1:
            trigg = 0
            pxmm = np.sqrt((ratio_coords[0,0]-ratio_coords[1,0])**2+(ratio_coords[0,1]-ratio_coords[1,1])**2)
            print(pxmm)
        

def pick_single():
    global st_cent, counter, store_centers, txt_files, plotwidth, plotheight,dpi
    
    #destroy all widgets associated with the frame
    for widget in frame1.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    
    counter += 1
    if counter > len(txt_files):
        counter = len(txt_files)
        
    scale = imageio.imread(txt_files[counter])
    
    
    # problems are likely somewhere in the remains of the function
    frame1.update()
    dpi = root.winfo_fpixels('1i')
    plotwidth = frame1.winfo_width() / dpi
    plotheight = frame1.winfo_height() / dpi
    
    # create plot
    fig1 = create_plot(image_cur=scale)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=frame1)
    
    mplcursors.cursor(fig1)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.X, expand=1)

    toolbar = Toolbar(canvas, frame1, pack_toolbar=False)
    toolbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=X)
    toolbar.update()
    
    fig1.canvas.callbacks.connect('button_press_event', pickc)
    


I tried destroying widgets in the frame, clearing the canvas, etc. Nothing seems to work.
